# Changing Product/Subscription Attribtue Term slug in WC Subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I run a webshop offering subscriptions. The subscription product has a 'brush' attribute with different terms, with the following notation:

- Term name: No. 1
- Term slug: no-1

We want to change the internal slug to 'am55' instead of 'no-1'. However, when simply changing the slug to 'am55' (in a test environment), all existing subscriptions get their brush attribute changed to the old 'no-1' slug, instead of the new slug (with old term name). I understand these terms are thus identified by their slug instead of ID. Is there any way to correctly change the term slug, without running SQL-queries on thousands of subscriptions/orders?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Since no one seems to know of a fix, perhaps a different solution to my problem: instead of changing the slugs to 'am##', they keep their own slugs. However, then the problem is that there is an existing No.4 (no-4) brush, that will still be named No. 4 to the users that currently have it in their subscription. A new brush also named No. 4 will be added to choose for new subscription, obviously needing a different slug than no-4. Anyone know of any neat solutions to add the new brush and have the two No. 4 brushes exist concurrently (at least for a while).

Comment: Is there any way I can further clarify the question?